# Google Maps V3 geocoding and markers in loop

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, closures, geocoding

I have some problems with my code, I have a list of airports in a sql database, and I want to create markers for each 1 of those airports.

For the address i got ICAO-codes for each airport, an ICAO is unique for each airport

I get the data from the Database as array

it's is saved in "temp" with an split function and with the for-loop it get them 1 by 1

Geocoding is not the problem, but I don't know why for the TITLE and the on click event
it is always the last one from the array which is used.

here is the page, the last entry in the database is ZBAA.

And all the markers are placed at the correct location but the title is wrong :s

http://mizar.lte.lu/~pr1011_meteo/projet/cartemonde4.php

The problem is with "address" i think but i m not sure.

```
for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; ++i){

     var address=temp[i];

     geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address}, function(results){            
          var marker  = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map, 
              position: results[0].geometry.location,
              title:address
          });

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
               window.open ('infomonde.php?icao='+address+'&language=fr', 'Informations météo', config='height=400, width=850, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no')});
     });  
};
```

Comment: it has to do w/ the i that you pass for `address=temp[i]` seems like you need to do a closure and pass in `address` but i can't be sure without putting a jsfiddle demo up

Comment: do u mind supplying some dummy fields for address/temp array?

Comment: what is that about the closure ? and what do you mean with dummy fields? if You mean by that to put some wrong entrys i already tried and the geocoding failed ^^

Comment: @user657848 take a look at my example and explore the demo.  let me know if you have any questions and feel free to comment

Answer (score 10):

Here is a [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/BMar7/) using "dummy" addresses and alert to show the correct data associate with each marker:

What you have is a typical closure/scope issue within the for loop.  To fix the issue use closure to localize the `temp[i]` variable before passing into geocode and callback function within it:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; ++i) {
        (function(address) {
            geocoder.geocode({
                'address': address
            }, function(results) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    title: address
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    //alert(address);  //use alert to debug address
                    window.open('infomonde.php?icao=' + address + '&language=fr', 'Informations météo', config = 'height=400, width=850, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no')
                });
            });
        })(temp[i]);  //closure passing in temp[i] and use address within the closure
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

my guess is because

```
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address}, function(results){ ... });
```

callback is execute in same context.

try execute marker in same context. the code below is will wait for all geocoder fetched. then parse to marker.

```
var results = {};
var waiting = temp.length;

while(temp.length > 0){

  var fetching = temp.pop();

  geocoder.geocode(
    { address: fetching}, 
    function(response){
      results[fetching] = response[0].geometry.location;
      --waiting;
      if(waiting == 0) // wait for everything to finish
        setMarker();
    }
  );
}
var setMarker = function(){
  for(var element in results){
    var marker  = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map, 
              position: results[element],
              title: element
              });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    window.open ('infomonde.php?icao='+element+'&language=fr', '', 'configs')});
  }
}
```

ps window.open if i'm not mistaken, some browser reject popup title(and might cause unable to open popup). i alway leave blank.

Comment: so i should keep address=temp[i] ? cuz you used it in your geocode

Comment: { address: address} change to { address: fetching} my mistake