# Unlimited Markers on Google map without query Limit using Geocoder

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map with multiple markers.I done that using google map Geocoder with the help of this link [Geocoder usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292060/google-maps-v3-geocoding-and-markers-in-loop) .But,it was limited to some markers only.After the limit it is showing the error as queryLimit.Is there any way to show the multiple markers on the map without any limit.It can be other than Geocoder too.Thanks

Comment: When you say "multiple markers", how many is that? Is it possible you are reaching the Terms of Service daily usage limits for the Geocoder?

Comment: I am getting after displaying nearly 15 markers on the map.Other than Geocoder is there is any other way to have multiple markers using Lat/Longitude or address

Answer (score 1):

You should never use a webservice or API to get the locations every time you want to show the markers. What you need to do is store the latitude and longitude somewhere. Preferably the same place you are storing the address information. Then just use those latitudes and longitudes to generate the markers with no need to worry about query limits.

The reason you are exceeding the query limit is that you are doing the queries too fast. If you have a period between each query you can do a lot more before hitting the querying cap, but this is not a solution. You should always save the location instead of querying every time :)